# How can I update finished Chart.js page Flask - filter a chart between dates?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, charts

How can I update an already rendered built finished Chart.js page Flask? There is already ready Chart.js on the template page. The value data for which is taken from Flask. After what action on the page the values in the Flask code changed. How can I make it so that after a certain action in the route, Flask is additionally updated Chart.js?

I have been thinking for a long time how to make it so that it is updated Chart.js when I change the values in the Flask route ("/range") - I can transfer them (changed DataFrame values) to the database - but then I don't know how to update Chart.js.

You will save me if you help with any help, links to something. How can this be done.

How to transfer data (values) between routes Flask?

it's html code

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" name="From" id="From" class="form-control" placeholder="From Date"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" name="to" id="to" class="form-control" placeholder="To Date"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="button" name="range" id="range" value="Range" class="btn btn-success"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="purchase_order"></div>
      <hr>
      <div class="row" style="align-content: center">
{#        <div class="col col-lg-0"></div>#}

            </div>
            <div class="outer-wrapper" style="align-content: center">
                <div class="table-wrapper" id="table-wrapper" style="align-content: center">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            {% for col in column_names %}
                            <th>{{col}}</th>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for row in row_data %}
                            <tr>
                                {% for cell in row %}
                                <td>{{ cell }}</td>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
{#        <div class="col col-lg-0"></div>#}
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div>
              <canvas id="myChart" width="800px" style="align-content: center"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
```

It's script

```
</script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $.datepicker.setDefaults({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });
            $(function (){
                $("#From").datepicker();
                $("#to").datepicker();
            });
            $('#range').click(function (){
                var From = $('#From').val();
                var to = $('#to').val();
                if (From != '' && to != '')
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"/range",
                        method:"POST",
                        data:{From:From, to:to},
                        success:function (data)
                        {
                            $('#table-wrapper').html(data);
                            $('#table-wrapper').append(data.htmlresponse);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Please Select the Date")
                }
            });
        });
    </script>


    <script>
      const labels = [{% for item in os_x %}
      "{{ item }}",
          {% endfor %}];

      const data = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
          label: 'My First dataset',
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          data: [{% for item in os_y %}
              {{ item }},
              {% endfor %}],
        }]
      };

      const config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: {}
      };
    </script>
    <script>
      const myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config
      );
    </script>
```

it's Flask routes

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
@app.route('/index')
def home_page():  # put application's code here
    df = pd.read_sql('select * from kotel', con=db.engine)
    df['date'] = df['date'].dt.round('2min')
    y_data = df['tnv'].tolist()
    x_data = df['date'].tolist()
    df_graph = df.copy()
    return render_template('index new.html', column_names=df.columns.values, row_data=list(df.values.tolist()), column_names_graph=df_graph.columns.values, os_y = y_data, os_x = x_data)


@app.route("/range", methods=["POST","GET"])
def range():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        From = request.form['From']
        to = request.form['to']
        df = pd.read_sql('select * from kotel', con=db.engine)
        df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
        df = df.loc[(df['date'] >= From) & (df['date'] <= to)]
        df['date'] = df['date'].dt.round('2min')
    return jsonify({'htmlresponse': render_template('response.html', column_names=df.columns.values, row_data=list(df.values.tolist()))})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this](https://github.com/roniemartinez/real-time-charts-with-flask) github page and it will have more details in how to do, but basically you have to set a data steam on the flask server and event listener on the js client.